# como cuento las vocales y consonantes de cada palabra en una lista de palabras ej: [["perro 2 voc y 3 cons"], ["gato 2 voc y 2 cons"]]

Tags: python

**esta es para cargar la lista de palabras a utilizar**

```
def carga():
  lista = []
  for _ in range(3):
    palabra = input("ingrese palabra: ")
    palabras = [palabra]
    lista.append(palabras)
  return lista
```

**esta es la formula para contar vocales y consonantes pero no se como unirla para que tome como parametro la lista de la funcion anterior**

```
def vocales(palabras):
  contador = 0
  contadorc = 0
  for x in palabras:
    if x in ('aeiou'):
      contador+=1
    if x in ('bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyz'):
      contadorc+=1
  s = (str(contador)+" vocales y " +str(contadorc)+" consonantes")
  return s
carga()
a= input("ingrese: ")
print(vocales(a))
```

Comment: al añadir la lista de palabras, haces `lista.append(vocales(palabras))` y listo! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Hice una ligera modificación a tu código, en la función `carga` al momento de apilar cada palabra a la lista. Debido a que estabas poniendo `[` y `]` lo apilaba como una lista pero tomaba toda la palabra como un elemento, por ejemplo, si introducias abc no obtenías `['a', 'b', 'c']`, en su lugar encontrabas `['abc']`, toda la palabra como un elemento entonces terminabas teniendo una lista de listas. Al quitarlos, obtienes una lista de strings lo cual facilita el procesamiento en la función `vocales()`.

Debido a que tu función `carga()` ya retorna tu lista de palabras, puedes hace otro `for in` para recorrer cada palabra y procesarla individualmente.

```py
def carga():
    lista = []
    for _ in range(3):
        palabra = input("ingrese palabra: ")
        palabras = palabra # Aqui no apilar como
                           # lista, usar la palabra tal cual
        lista.append(palabras)
    return lista


def vocales(palabra):
    contador = 0
    contadorc = 0
    for letra in palabra:
        if letra in ('aeiou'):
            contador += 1
        if letra in ('bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyz'):
            contadorc += 1
    s = (str(contador)+" vocales y " + str(contadorc)+" consonantes")
    return s


palabras = carga()
resultados = []

for palabra in palabras:
    resultados.append(vocales(palabra))

print(resultados)
```

La función `carga()` quedó igual, solo hice un cambio en el nombre de algunas variables para que sea más legible.

Ejemplo de salida:

```
ingrese palabra: aeiou
ingrese palabra: abcdef
ingrese palabra: qqqaa
['5 vocales y 0 consonantes', '2 vocales y 4 consonantes', '2 vocales y 3 consonantes']
```

Nota que obtienes como resultado una lista de strings, si quieres una lista de listas (que en caso práctico y por la salida que tienes no sería lo ideal), tendrías que apilar de esta forma `resultados.append([vocales(palabra)])`.

**EDIT:** Función `vocales()` con las mejoras hechas por @Christian

```py
def vocales(palabra):
    contador = 0
    contadorc = 0
    for letra in palabra:
        if letra in 'aeiou':
            contador += 1
        elif letra in 'bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyz':
            contadorc += 1
    return f'{contador} vocales y {contadorc} consonantes'
```

Comment: Otra mejora sería utilizar `elif` y no un segundo `if` ya que no es necesario tener que evaluar nuevamente si la letra está en las consonantes si ya se determinó que está en las vocales, incluso se puede usar `else`, pero lo correcto sería usar `elif`. Por otra parte también se puede usar *f-strings* para hacer más agradable el resultado. Y por último se puede eliminar los paréntesis en los `if` dado que los strings son iterables solo basta `if letra in "aeiou"`

Comment: @Christian gracias por las sugerencias, ya las agregué a la respuesta. Solo tenía consiente la observación los *f-strings*, las otras no las recordaba.